# How to set the minimum and maximum boundaries of a list of values used in a function to calculate the average in R?

Tags: r, data-science

I am fairly new to R and Python, however, I am determined to continue learning more. Below (first attempt) is a portion of code that calls a function that accepts 3 parameters to calculate the average of alist of number values.

However, the range is unbounded and I'd like to have it between 0-100.

```
avglist(1:103,0,100)
# [1] 50
avglist(1:103,0,103)
# [1] 51.5
```

So it will keep the boundaries if set, however, I've tried to add a conditional if statement and only raised other issues. The second attempt below was my approach.

I have tried 2 separate if statements, in/out of the for loop etc. probably pretty basic trial-and-error. Adding the conditional if statement to confine the boundaries ended up excluding lists of values that were within range as well so I've hit a wall for now. Feel free to provide any advice and/or pick it apart.

First Attempt
Initialize number of values (n) and total sum of values (total)

```
# Define avglist function with 3 parameters (lst, a, b)
avglist <- function(lst, a = 0, b = 100) {
  n <- 0
  total <- 0
  # Begin for loop to iterate through values in list parameter
  for(i in lst) {
    # Iterate through values if value is between a and b
    if ((i > a) && (i < b)) {
      # Add one to the number of values count, add the value to total sum
      n <- n + 1
      total <- total + i
    }
  }
  # Returns the average of the list of values
  total/n
}

# 100 random numbers between 1 and 100, however, not in a sequence; 
# check to confirm average
avglist(runif(100,1,100),30,100)
# [1] 68.7141

# Returns 2 ((1+2+3) / 3 = 2)
avglist(1:3)
# [1] 2

# Returns 3.5 ((2+3+4+5) / 4 = 3.5)
avglist(2:5,2,5)
# [1] 3.5
```

Second Attempt

```
# Define avglist function with 3 parameters (lst, a, b)
avglist <- function(lst, a = 0, b = 100) {
  # Initialize number of values (n) and total sum of values (total)
  n <- 0
  total <- 0
  # Begin for loop to iterate through values in list parameter
  for (i in lst) {
    # Begin for loop to iterate through values in list parameter
    if ((i >= a) && (i <= b) && (a %in% (0:100)) && (b %in% (0:100))) {
      # Add one to the number of values count, add the value to total sum
      n <- (n+1)
      total <- (total+i)
    } else {
      print("Out of bounds. Please keep values between 0 and 100.")
    }
  } 
  total/n
}

 return(total/n)
 } else {
print("Out of bounds. Please keep values between 0 and 100.")

 }

}

avglist(runif(100,1,100),30,99)
# [1] "Out of bounds. Please keep values between 0 and 100."
 avglist(1:3)
# [1] 2
 avglist(2:5,2,5)
# [1] "Out of bounds. Please keep values between 0 and 100."\`
```

Read above hastags for small details. I have included some sample output as well. The code sections are described above using hastags.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a vectorized function to compute censored means. No need for `for` loops.

I have added an argument, `na.rm`, to make the function closer to base `mean`.

```r
avglist <- function(lst, a = 0, b = 100, na.rm = FALSE) {
  i <- lst > a & lst < b
  if(any(!i)) {
    msg <- sprintf("Out of bounds. Please keep values between %d and %d.", a, b)
    warning(msg)
  }
  mean(lst[i], na.rm = na.rm)
}

set.seed(2023)   # make the results reproducible

avglist(runif(100, 1, 100), 30, 99)
#> Warning in avglist(runif(100, 1, 100), 30, 99): Out of bounds. Please keep
#> values between 30 and 99.
#> [1] 63.56714
avglist(1:3)
#> [1] 2
avglist(2:5, 2, 5)
#> Warning in avglist(2:5, 2, 5): Out of bounds. Please keep values between 2 and
#> 5.
#> [1] 3.5
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the comment.

avglist(list(1,2,3), 1, 99)
[1] NA

Comment: The output is below. Even if the list is (2,3), it returns NA.
avglist(list(1,2,3), 1, 99)
[1] NA

I will have to look into that approach more so as it appears to be much cleaner. I think I have a modified version that catches everything except if the list includes characters (which I thought !is.numeric would resolve). list(1:"100") even returns the correct output. I will try adding it as an answer as it won't fit here.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Initialize number of values (n) & total sum of values (total)
n <- 0
total <- 0

# Create & define avglist function that accepts 3 parameters (lst, a, b)
avglist <- function(lst, a=0, b=100) {
  # If statement to ensure input values are between 1 & 99
  if ((a %in% 1:99) && (b %in% 1:99)) {
    # Begin for loop to iterate through values in list parameter
    for (i in lst) {
      # Iterate through values if value is between a & b
      if ((i>=a) && (i<=b)) {
        # Add one to the number of values count, add the value to total sum
        n <- (n+1)
        total <- (total+i)
      }
    }
    # Returns the average of the list of values
    return(total/n)
  # Else if statement if the input values are not numeric
  } else if (!is.numeric(lst) || !is.numeric(a) || !is.numeric(b)) {
    return("ERROR: One of the entries is not a number. Please enter only numbers.")
  # Else statement if a is less than/equal to 0 or if b is greater than/equal to 100   
  } else {
    print("ERROR: Out of range. Please enter numbers between 0 and 100.")
  }
}

avglist(list(1,2,3), 1, 99)
[1] 2

# Lower bounds
avglist(1:99, 0, 99)
[1] "ERROR: Out of range. Please enter numbers between 0 and 100."
avglist(1:99, 1, 99)
[1] 50

# Upper bounds
avglist(1:99, 1, 100)
[1] "ERROR: Out of range. Please enter numbers between 0 and 100."

# 2nd Parameter (a)
avglist(list(1,2,3), "a", 99)
[1] "ERROR: One of the entries is not a number. Please enter only numbers."

# 3rd Parameter (b)
avglist(list(1,2,3), 1, "b")
[1] "ERROR: One of the entries is not a number. Please enter only numbers."

# 1st Parameter (lst) 
avglist(1:"100", 1, 99)
[1] 50
```

Just haven't figured out how to catch everything in the list value, however, the a and b parameters are now constrained so it only calculates from 1:99.

Is it because lists are fairly flexible in terms of what can be accepted as input?